# How large is the Hilbert space required to be to realize a POVM via projective measurements?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-information

Neumark's theorem says that any POVM in $n$ dimensional Hilbert space can be realized as a projective measurement in $N$ (where $N > n$) dimensional Hilbert space.

Is any lower bound on $N$? In other words, how large is the Hilbert space required to be to illustrate $n$ dimensional POVM as projective measurement?

Any reference with the answer would be a great help.

Answer (score 3):

The lower bound is the number of outcomes of the POVM measurement. This could be equal to or larger than the Hilbert-space dimension $n$, but it could also be smaller, particularly if you're describing a partial projective measurement that destroys some coherences but not all of them.

The absolute lower bound is $N=1$, which corresponds to the single operator $\mathbb I$ in the POVM, which corresponds to a measurement which answers the question "does the system exist?", with a single (positive) possible answer.

Comment: I feel that the OP and you might be using N in a different meaning.  It feels to me what the OP calls N is what you would call N*n?

Comment: I suspect you're right, but OP's notation still looks rather ambiguous to me.

Comment: I agree.  I rather wanted to suggest that addint to the post that N is the dimension of the extra system you add for realizing the POVM projectively might be clarifying.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty: Did you mean that we need to add as many extra dimensions as many outcomes of POVMs we have in our $n$ dimensional Hilbert space.